# Creating a model with a foreign key mvc4 asp.net

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not exactly sure how to handle creating a model that has a foreign key.  I have to pass the foreign key to the model but I am not sure of the best way to handle this.

If you use the blog/post example from the [entity framework documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583):

You would pass your post model to your view:

```
@model BlogApp.Models.Post
```

Part of saving the model is putting in the BlogId, this would be a hidden field but in concept:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BlogId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BlogId)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BlogId)
</div>
```

How do you pass the blog ID from the current blog model so it can be saved in the Post BlogId field?

The options I can think of.

1. get the blog id in the post Get create and pass that in the ViewBag.
2. Add additional routing Rules so it is something like blog/2/post/create/3 and then somehow get the 2 and use it as the
   blogId
3. Set the BlogId in a Session Variable and set it for posts that in the Post create controller.

Are one of the above best practice or is there a different option I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

In your workflow the creating a blog post will be done after selecting a blog. So you can change url to have that as a query string variable,

```
/post/create?blogId=1
```

The **Create** action in the **Post** controller  will look like this,

```
    [HttpGet]
    public AcionResult Create(int blogId ){
        var post=new Post{BlogId=blogId}
        return view (post); 
    }
```

I think this is the easiest and a clean way to do it.